# Bitwise Operations -- Arithmetic Operations

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

Can you please explain the below lines, with some good examples.

> A left arithmetic shift by n is
>   equivalent to multiplying by 2<sup>n</sup>
>   (provided the value does not
>   overflow).

And:

> A right arithmetic
>   shift by n of a two's complement value
>   is equivalent to dividing by 2<sup>n</sup> and
>   rounding toward negative infinity. If
>   the binary number is treated as ones'
>   complement, then the same right-shift
>   operation results in division by 2<sup>n</sup>
>   and rounding toward zero.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure where you got this quote from, but a left arithmetic shift by n is equivalent to multiplying by 2^n (*not* 2n).  Similarly for right arithmetic shift.

Comment: I added the awesomeness that is <sup> tags, since this question really deserved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will explain what happens in a base that we're more familiar with: 10.

In base 10, let's say you have a number N=123. Now, you "shift" this number to the left k=3 positions, filling the emptied digits with 0. So you get X=123000.

Note that X = N * 10<sup>k</sup>.

The case with base 2 is analogous.

```
 Example 1 (base 10)   |  Example 2 (base 2)
                       |
 N        =    123     |  N       =   110101 (53 in base 10)
 k        =      3     |  k       =        2 (in base 10)
 N << k   = 123000     |  N << k  = 11010100 (212 in base 10)
                       |
 10^k     =   1000     |  2^k     =      100 (in base 2; 4 in base 10)
 N * 10^k = 123000     |  N * 2^k = 11010100 (53 * 4 = 212 in base 10)
                       |
```

The case with right shift is simply a mirror of the process, and is also analogous in base 10. For example, if I have 123456 in base 10, and I "shift" right 3 positions, I get 123. This is 123456 / 1000 (integer division), where 1000 = 10<sup>3</sup>.

Comment: Any Good website or document, on Problems on Bit Manipulations.... Need it for good understanding of it..

Comment: Right shift becomes more interesting when you look at negative numbers.  The sign bit is extended, and you end up with the weird-looking behavior of `-1 >> n` being equal to -1 but `1 >> n` being equal to 0 (for any positive `n`).

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift

Comment: Well I am reading from wikipedia onlyy.. But i am thinking of few examples, in which these conditions are met.. Hope you mite can help out..

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to create your own examples.

Consider five which is `101` in binary. Left shift it once and you get `1010` which is binary for ten. Do it again and you get `10100` which is twenty and so on..