# extra storage merge sort

Tags: java, algorithm

I need make a merge sort using an additional array. Here is my code:

```
public class extra_storage{  
    public static void main(String[]args) { 

        int x[]=new int[]{12,9,4,99,120,1,3,10};
        int a[]=new int[x.length];

        mergesort(x,0,x.length-1,a);
        for (int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
            System.out.println(x[i]);
        }       
    }

    public static void mergesort(int x[],int low,int high, int a[]){      
        if (low>=high) {
            return;
        }
        int middle=(low+high)/2;
        mergesort(x,low,middle,a);
        mergesort(x,middle+1,high,a);
        int k;
        int lo=low;
        int h=high;
        for (k=low;k<high;k++)
            if ((lo<=middle ) && ((h>high)||(x[lo]<x[h]))){
                a[k]=x[lo++];
            }
            else {
                a[k]=x[h++];
            }
        for (k=low;k<=high;k++){
            x[k]=a[k];
        }     
    }
}
```

But something is wrong. When I run it the output is this:

```
1
0
3
0
4
0
9
0
```

What is the problem?

Comment: For the love of whatever, please put braces after `for` - I know that it'll do what it looks like you want it to do based on your indentation, but good luck to anyone who wants to add a statement after your `else`.

Comment: explain what the intent of the code is.  What is the "additional array" for?

Comment: And stop changing the question!

Comment: @Pyrolistical: Merge sorting an array is not an in-place algorithm; the "additional array" is needed as a workspace for the sorting task.

Comment: @Joey Merge sort can easily be as an in place algorithm. There's nothing done in the additional array that couldn't be done in the original.

Comment: @glowcoder Feel free to update the 7th paragraph of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergesort#Analysis accordingly :-)

Comment: The code (as it is now) does not print anything. It throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException!

Comment: @Joey yepp. @glowcoder, An in-place version of merge-sort is just a plain bitch to write - it's anything but easy.

Comment: @corsiKa I would like to see an example of such an easy merge-sort !?

Comment: @user492238 From wikipedia, "One way to sort in-place is to merge the blocks recursively.[4] Like the standard merge sort, in-place merge sort is also a stable sort. Stable sorting of linked lists is simpler. In this case the algorithm does not use more space than that the already used by the list representation, but the O(log(k)) used for the recursion trace."

Comment: @corsika A good example, that wikipedia is not God! if you follow the link to the Java implementation, you'll realize, they use a temporary arrays to do the merge.

Comment: @user492238 fine then. If their implementation is bad, I reviewed this one and found it good: http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~harrison/Java/MergeSortAlgorithm.java.html It's clear that it's part of a demonstration framework and as such has tools in it to pause itself and kill itself which are unnecessary. But it's very clear there are no additional arrays being created to sort, and it's not that difficult to follow.

Comment: @corsika right. It does not need additional temp storage. Unfortunately its effort is O(n^2). :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have a stack overflow.

In your code

```
public static void mergesort(int x[],int low,int high, int a[]){      
    if (low>high) {
        return;
    }
    int middle=(low+high)/2;
    mergesort(x,low,middle,a);
    mergesort(x,middle+1,high,a);
```

If low starts off lower or equal to high, then it will end up equal to high, in which case middle==low==high and it will call itself forever.

---

## Question was changed to remove stack overflow after answer submitted.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your original algorithm with some corrections and stylistic improvements:

```
public class MergeSort {  
    public static void main(String[]args) { 
        int[] nums = {12,9,4,99,120,1,3,10};
        mergeSort(nums);
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(nums));
        // "[1, 3, 4, 9, 10, 12, 99, 120]"
    }
    static void mergeSort(int[] arr) {
        mergeSort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1, new int[arr.length]);
    }
    static void mergeSort(int[] arr, int low, int high, int[] buff){
        if (low >= high) {
            return;
        }
        int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
        mergeSort(arr, low, mid, buff);
        mergeSort(arr, mid+1, high, buff);
        for (int left = low, right = mid + 1, i = low; i <= high; i++) {
            if (right > high || left <= mid && arr[left] <= arr[right]) {
                buff[i] = arr[left++];
            } else {
                buff[i] = arr[right++];
            }
        }
        for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) {
            arr[i] = buff[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Unlike Eyal's implementation, where the role of `src` and `dst` are swapped back and forth through the levels of recursion, here we always sort to the same array object `arr`, and the array object `buff` is always used only as a temporary buffer for merging (and consequently, there's a copy phase after the merge phase). This is still `O(N log N)`, but Eyal's more advanced implementation will be a constant-factor improvement.

#### On the merge loop

Essentially you have a `left` index for the left subarray, and `right` index for the right subarray, and you pick the right element from either the `left` or `right` to put into `buff`.

The valid range of elements are (inclusive bounds):

- `left = low...mid` for left subarray
- `right = mid+1...high` for right subarray

To evaluate which element to pick, consider the condition under which the `left` element is picked. It happens when:

- There are no more element to pick from the right subarray (i.e. `right > high`)
- ***OR*** (conditionally) there's still an element to pick from the left subarray (i.e. `left <= mid`) and (conditionally) that element is less than or equal to the element from the right subarray (i.e. `arr[left] <= arr[right]`).

It's important to use short-circuiting conditional-and `&&` ([JLS 15.23](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.23)) and conditional-or `||` ([JLS 15.24](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.24)) operators here, and to order these conditions accordingly. Otherwise you'll get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

#### Related questions

- [What’s the difference between | and || in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96667/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-java)
- [Shortcut “or-assignment” (|=) operator in Java
  Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486472/shortcut-or-assignment-operator-in-java/)
- [Why doesn’t Java have compound assignment versions of the conditional-and and conditional-or operators? (&&=, ||=)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324549/why-doesnt-java-have-compound-assignment-versions-of-the-conditional-and-and-con)

---

#### On finding average between two numbers

It's common to see the following:

```
int mid = (low + high) / 2; // BROKEN! Can result in negative!
```

The problem is that nowadays, arrays/lists etc can easily exceed 2<sup>30</sup> elements, and the above would cause an overflow and results in a negative number.

The new idiom, as advocated by Josh Bloch, is the following:

```
int mid = (low + high) >>> 1; // WORKS PERFECTLY!
```

This uses the unsigned right shift operator ([JLS 15.19](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.19)); it handles any overflow on the addition correctly for our need.

#### References

- [Official Google Research Blog: Nearly All Binary Searches and Mergesorts are Broken](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html)

#### Related questions

- [Bitwise Operations — Arithmetic Operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800752/bitwise-operations-arithmetic-operations/)

  - Explains how bitwise shifting relates to power-of-two arithmetics
- [Java’s >> versus >>> Operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034640/javas-versus-operator)
- [Difference between >>> and >> operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972356/difference-between-and-operators)
- [Difference between >>> and >>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811319/difference-between-and)

---

#### On array declarations

Do not make a habit of declaring arrays like this:

```
int x[];
```

You should instead put the brackets with the *type*, rather than with the *identifier*:

```
int[] x;
```

#### Related questions

- [Is there any difference between `Object[] x` and `Object x[]` ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229602/is-there-any-difference-between-object-x-and-object-x)
- [Difference between `int[] myArray` and `int myArray[]` in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454921/difference-between-int-myarray-and-int-myarray-in-java)
- [in array declaration `int[] k,i` and `int k[],i`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102703/in-array-declaration-int-k-i-and-int-k-i)

  - These declarations result in different types for `i`!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not clear enough, and it has many irrelevant operations. Furthermore, it doesn't exhibit the behavior you describe.

The idea of the mergesort version you are trying to implement is to use a single auxiliary array (*source array*) of the same size as the input array (*destination array*). This allows merging from one array into the other, since there is no efficient in-place merging technique. The algorithm consists of sorting the two halves of the destination array into the corresponding ranges in the source array, and then merging back the two halves into the destination array. Note that this requires that in every invocation the two arrays are identical in the range specified by low and high.

Following is such an implementation for int arrays. You can add optimizations like doing insertion sorts for small inputs, or appending halves instead of merging them when possible. This kind of optimizations can be found in the implementation of [Arrays.sort(Object[])](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html?noframes=true#sort(java.lang.Object[])).

```
public static void mergeSort(int[] arr){
    int[] aux = arr.clone();
    mergeSort(aux, 0, arr.length, arr);
}

private static void mergeSort(int[] src, int low,  int high, int[] dst) {
    // One or no items - nothing to sort  
    if (high-low<=1)
        return;

    // Recursively sorting into src
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    mergeSort(dst, low, mid, src);
    mergeSort(dst, mid, high, src);

    // Merge halves into dst
    for(int i = low, p = low, q = mid; i < high; i++) {
        if (q >= high || p < mid && src[p] <= src[q])
            dst[i] = src[p++];
        else
            dst[i] = src[q++];
    }
}
```